# Cognos Aggregation: An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='-28'

Tags: report, aggregate, cognos

I get this error when trying to apply an aggregate function to a column, I want to total it, but even count doesn't work. I'm trying to get the number of locations with no inventory located to them.

```
An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='-28'.
```

Here's the formula i'm using for the data

```
CASE
WHEN ( [Actual Cases] = '' )
THEN (1)
ELSE (0)
END
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have searched for this and everyone says inconsistent data type, but I'm clearly passing 1's and 0's so im stumped.

Here's the details on the error:

```
UDA-SQL-0114 The cursor supplied to the operation "sqlOpenResult" is inactive.UDA-SQL-      0107   A general exception has occurred during the operation "open result".[IBM][CLI   Driver][AS] SQL0302N The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is too large for its corresponding use. SQLSTATE=22023 RSV-SRV-0042 Trace back:RSReportService.cpp(722): QFException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSReportService::process()RSReportServiceMethod.cpp(263): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSReportServiceMethod::process(): asynchRunSpecification_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(808): QFException: RSASyncExecutionThread::checkExceptionRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(260): QFException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSASyncExecutionThread::runImpl(): asynchRunSpecification_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(864): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSASyncExecutionThread::processCommand(): asynchRunSpecification_RequestExecution/RSRenderExecution.cpp(670): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSRenderExecution::executeAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(291): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSLayoutAssembly.cpp(79): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSLayoutAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSReportPagesAssembly.cpp(179): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSReportPagesAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSPageAssembly.cpp(303): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSPageAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableRowAssembly.cpp(177): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSTableRowAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableCellAssembly.cpp(137): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSTableCellAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(662): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSAssembly::createListIteratorAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(717): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSAssembly::createListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1055): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::getListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1131): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::getResultSetIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1295): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::createIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1569): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgr.cpp(1559): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(168): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(160): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()QFSSession.cpp(1147): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1145): QFException: CCL_CAUGHT: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1102): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1078): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSConnection.cpp(788): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSConnection::ExecuteQFSQuery.cpp(213): QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSQuery::Execute v2CoordinationQFSQuery.cpp(4456): QFException: CCL_THROW: CoordinationPlanner
```

Comment: NVM. the data being brought in was a number, not a string, so i was getting the hang up here [ WHEN ( [Actual Cases] = '' ) ]

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a datatype mismatch -- this hypothesis is also supported by your comments. :) But this is one of many Cognos generic errors. Sometimes a better error is listed way down in the Cognos error report so try to post the whole thing, but frequently Cognos won't give you much to sink your teeth into.

If you have SQL access to your database or a similar (dev) version then you can generate the SQL for the query subject in Report Studio via the Properties menu, then cut-and-paste the Native SQL into your SQL program to get a better error (or analyze/explain to hunt for slowdowns).

If you don't have SQL access you can try creating a SQL-based query subject in Report Studio and run it in tabular mode to see if it generates a more helpful error.